# Custom GL Lines Plug-in creates error on paid in full invoices

Tags: plugins, netsuite, suitescript, invoice

I created a script that re-books certain transactions depending on the account they were booked to. The script is running fine on all invoices and creating the expected outcome except when an invoice has the status "paid in full". The error states `Cannot use 0 as input to setDebitAmount(). Amount to debit must be positive`.
Already tried the script on the same invoice with different statuses - same outcome.

Why does the invoice status make a difference here?

```
/**
 * Custom GL lines Plug-In Implementation for rebooking Invoices (articles and discounts)
 * Configuration of Plug-In Implementation:
 *    Transaction Type: Invoice
 *    Subsidiaries: MTE
 * @param {*} transactionRecord
 * @param {*} standardLines
 * @param {*} customLines
*/
function customizeGlImpact(
    transactionRecord,
    standardLines,
    customLines
) {
    function sign(x) {
        // If x is NaN, the result is NaN.
        // If x is -0, the result is -0.
        // If x is +0, the result is +0.
        // If x is negative and not -0, the result is -1.
        // If x is positive and not +0, the result is +1.
        return ((x > 0) - (x < 0)) || +x;
    }

    if (standardLines.getCount() > 0) {
        var tranid = transactionRecord.getFieldValue("tranid");
        var customername = transactionRecord.getFieldValue("entityname");

        for (var i = 0; i < standardLines.getCount(); i++) {
            // get information for GL standard line
            var currLineStandard = standardLines.getLine(i);
            var taxCodeId = currLineStandard.getTaxItemId();
            var accountID = currLineStandard.getAccountId();

            nlapiLogExecution("debug", "Line: " + i, JSON.stringify({ "taxCodeId": taxCodeId, "accountID": accountID }));

            if (taxCodeId === null || accountID === null) {// specific lines don't have accountID
                continue;
            }

            var correctAccountId = targetAccountSearch(accountID, taxCodeId);

            nlapiLogExecution("debug", "Line: " + i, JSON.stringify({ "correctAccountId": correctAccountId }));

            if (correctAccountId === -1) {
                continue;
            }

            if (correctAccountId !== accountID) {
                var salestaxitem = nlapiLoadRecord("salestaxitem", taxCodeId);

                var newLine = customLines.addNewLine();
                if (currLineStandard.creditAmount === "0") {
                    if (sign(currLineStandard.debitAmount) === 1) {
                        newLine.setCreditAmount(currLineStandard.debitAmount);
                    } else {
                        newLine.setDebitAmount(currLineStandard.debitAmount);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (sign(currLineStandard.creditAmount) === 1) {
                        newLine.setDebitAmount(currLineStandard.creditAmount);
                    } else {
                        newLine.setCreditAmount(currLineStandard.creditAmount);
                    }
                }

                newLine.setAccountId(accountID);
                newLine.setLocationId(currLineStandard.getLocationId());
                newLine.setDepartmentId(currLineStandard.getDepartmentId());
                newLine.setClassId(currLineStandard.getClassId());
                newLine.setEntityId(currLineStandard.getEntityId());
                newLine.setMemo((
                    "Umbuchung " +
                    salestaxitem.getFieldValue("itemid") +
                    " - " +
                    tranid +
                    " - " +
                    customername +
                    (currLineStandard.getMemo() !== null ? " - " + currLineStandard.getMemo() : "")).substring(0, 100)
                );

                var newLine = customLines.addNewLine();
                if (currLineStandard.creditAmount === "0") {
                    if (sign(currLineStandard.debitAmount) === 1) {
                        newLine.setDebitAmount(currLineStandard.debitAmount);
                    } else {
                        newLine.setCreditAmount(currLineStandard.debitAmount);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (sign(currLineStandard.creditAmount) === 1) {
                        newLine.setCreditAmount(currLineStandard.creditAmount);
                    } else {
                        newLine.setDebitAmount(currLineStandard.creditAmount);
                    }
                }
                newLine.setAccountId(correctAccountId);
                newLine.setLocationId(currLineStandard.getLocationId());
                newLine.setDepartmentId(currLineStandard.getDepartmentId());
                newLine.setClassId(currLineStandard.getClassId());
                newLine.setEntityId(currLineStandard.getEntityId());
                newLine.setMemo((
                    "Umbuchung " +
                    salestaxitem.getFieldValue("itemid") +
                    " - " +
                    tranid +
                    " - " +
                    customername +
                    (currLineStandard.getMemo() !== null ? " - " + currLineStandard.getMemo() : "")).substring(0, 100)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param {*} custrecord_pg_source_account
 * @param {*} custrecord_pg_lookup_tax_code
 * @returns
 */
function targetAccountSearch(
    custrecord_pg_source_account,
    custrecord_pg_lookup_tax_code
) {
    // saved search for mapping
    var accountRebookingSearch = nlapiCreateSearch(
        "customrecord_pg_account_rebooking",
        [
            nlobjSearchFilter(
                "custrecord_pg_source_account",
                null,
                "is",
                custrecord_pg_source_account
            ),
            nlobjSearchFilter(
                "custrecord_pg_lookup_tax_code",
                null,
                "is",
                custrecord_pg_lookup_tax_code
            ),
            nlobjSearchFilter(
                "isinactive",
                null,
                "is",
                "F"
            )
        ],
        [
            new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_pg_source_account'),
            new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_pg_lookup_tax_code'),
            new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_pg_target_account')
        ]
    );

    // run search
    var accountRebookingSearchResults = accountRebookingSearch
        .runSearch()
        .getResults(0, 2);

    accountRebookingSearchResults = JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(accountRebookingSearchResults)
    );

    nlapiLogExecution("debug", "accountRebookingSearchResults", JSON.stringify({ "accountRebookingSearchResults": accountRebookingSearchResults }));

    if (accountRebookingSearchResults.length === 0) {
        return -1; // no mapping found
    }

    if (accountRebookingSearchResults.length > 1) {
        throw "more than one mapping found";
    }

    var accountRebookingSearchResult = accountRebookingSearchResults[0];

    return parseInt(accountRebookingSearchResult.columns.custrecord_pg_target_account.internalid);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the standardlines contains datalines with credit amoung && debit amount == 0. Why that is, I don't know - maybe someone knows and leaves a comment about that. So all I needed was a check for both values.